# Error importing csv products in magento

Tags: magento, csv, import, export, dataflow

Good Morning,

I've been dealing with this issue for a while now, I've been trying to import products .csv file to Magento but I'm getting an error (Shows image below). When I try to import it through system => import/export => dataflow/profiles => Run profile. It doesn't uploads every product, always gives me an error when it reaches the 43rd product. I tried importing 5 files, everything went well but when it hits that product it doesn't goes through. The file is a CSV (separated comma) UTF-8 (checked). I exported the product list from Magento and started to add products from there. I checked every column and they are all the same in the same order.

I tried to import the file from system => import/export => import and it gives me an error ( Column name: "store" are invalid ) that the first column on the file. Everything seems right.

Any ideas of How to fix this problem? I'm going to try to get the csv file using apache openOffice to see if there's any difference.

I'll keep you posted if I found the solution.

[image] [image]
Thank you. 
First Row CSV file:

store,websites,attribute_set,type,category_ids,sku,has_options,name,meta_title,meta_description,image,small_image,thumbnail,url_key,url_path,page_layout,options_container,image_label,small_image_label,thumbnail_label,msrp_enabled,msrp_display_actual_price_type,gift_message_available,itemname,make,price,special_price,weight,msrp,status,is_recurring,visibility,tax_class_id,magikfeatured,magikrecommended,product_socialbar,special_from_date,special_to_date,news_from_date,news_to_date,custom_design_from,custom_design_to,description,short_description,meta_keyword,custom_layout_update,qty,min_qty,use_config_min_qty,is_qty_decimal,backorders,use_config_backorders,min_sale_qty,use_config_min_sale_qty,max_sale_qty,use_config_max_sale_qty,is_in_stock,low_stock_date,notify_stock_qty,use_config_notify_stock_qty,manage_stock,use_config_manage_stock,stock_status_changed_auto,use_config_qty_increments,qty_increments,use_config_enable_qty_inc,enable_qty_increments,is_decimal_divided,stock_status_changed_automatically,use_config_enable_qty_increments,product_name,store_id,product_type_id,product_status_changed,product_changed_websites,custom_design,country_of_manufacture,fourseason,omega,uac,gr_ean,gr_valid_through

*** UPDATE ***

I saved the file in excel as UTF-8 (I was doing that step after saving file as csv with a text editor) and tried to upload but now I'm getting this error.

[image]

I feel I did a step forward but still I haven't been able to find a solution.

** UPDATE *** 
After checking the first row and doing some changes, like duplicate column names and columns without the underscore in the beginning (_store,_type ... etc) I'm getting this error.[image]

I believe I've found the spot why if I use a dataflow profile doesn't upload from the 45th product.

I've been thinking that it might be a server problem? any ideas?

Comment: Can you update your question with your sample csv file values?

Comment: I added the first row of the csv file to check the columns.

Comment: What value are you providing under store column numeric or store name?

Comment: under I have: store => admin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steps to import products in Magento:

1.- Take a deep breath.

2.- Have some relaxing tea.

3.- Create a test product manually, with all your attributes.
    Create categories. ( Use MageWorks for bulk import of categories )
4.- Export products.csv file, from system => export

5.- Add another test file in the exported file.

6.- Check if it got imported.

7.- Edit the exported adding products file in Excel (Do not touch first row [attributes] )

8.- I ain't sure about this but Magento 1.9 doesn't use category_ids, it uses _category and the value is the actual path within categories example. Products/Vehicles/ADAPTERS ==> Being 'Products' the main category id(2).

[categories_id] may work for some people but in my experience it didn't work for me, it was creating path errors.

9.- Save csv file. Make sure is UTF-8 without BOOM. Use Notepad++ to make sure you save the encoding.

10.- Import file using system=>import. the system will check data and if everything is fine you should have a green light.

Note:
Every time you edit and save the file in Excel it will change the encoding again to ANSI. SO make sure the file is UTF-8 W/O BOOM.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It argued on 'type' column, though I had the one filled in the file. Then I resaved with UTF-8 without BOM, but is helped only when I have added column '_product_websites' with vales - base. Check your file, there should be all the required by Magento fields

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you man. After a lot of work and I huge headache I realized that every time I saved the file in Excel, this change the encoding to ANSI, then I was using notepad top change to UTF-8. What I didn't realized is that it HAS to be UTF-8 W/O BOOM. Downloaded Notepad++ and it did the job. I found a few others typing mistakes too.